# Why aren't knex migration not showing in psql database?

Tags: psql, knex.js

I created `knexfile.js`

```
 module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      filename: 'postgres://localhost/myDB'
    }
  }, 
};
```

Then I create migration

```
npx knex migrate:make items
```

And have this data

```
 exports.up = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable("items", (table) => {
      table.increments("id").primary();
      table.string("title").notNullable();
      table.string("description");
      table.decimal("price").notNullable();
      table.decimal("quantity").unsigned().notNullable();
      table.string("image");
    });
  }; 
  exports.down = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists("items");
  };
```

Then I run `npx knex migrate:latest`

And it indicates that one was migrated

Then I go into `psql myDB`, run `\dt` and nothing comes up!